# Calling a function from a button

Tags: ios, uibutton

Can anyone help me to understand what is going wrong with my function below pls?

I'm fairly new to native IOS dev.

I wanted to implement a side panel into our app using this tutorial (http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/).
All that works fine and is straightforward enough - but I wanted to trigger the reveal functionality via a standard button rather than a dynamic button in the header - to suit our design..

The original code is as follows -

```
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"


// Change button color
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

// Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.
_sidebarButton.target = self.revealViewController;
_sidebarButton.action = @selector(revealToggle:);

// Set the gesture
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
```

to replicate that functionality triggered by a button I added the following to the .h file -

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *sidebarButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *revealLeftBtn;
- (IBAction)btnClickRevealL:(id)sender;
```

and the following in my .m file

```
- (IBAction)btnClickRevealL:(id)sender {


[self.revealViewController];
[@selector(revealToggle:)];

}
```

I get the error 'suspected identifier' for the above lines - I dont understand how the functions triggered with the previous method and not with the above - can anyone help?
Cheers

for reference this is the entire .M file -

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"


@interface MainViewController ()

@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

self.title = @"";

// Change button color
_sidebarButton.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.96f alpha:0.2f];

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:TRUE];

// Set the side bar button action. When it's tapped, it'll show up the sidebar.






// Set the gesture
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnClickRevealL:(id)sender {


[self.revealViewController];
[@selector(revealToggle:)];

}
@end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line:

```
 (IBAction)btnClickRevealL:(id)sender {


[self.revealViewController];
[@selector(revealToggle:)];

}
```

Does nothing.

I guess this is what you want to do:

```
[self.revealViewController revealToggle:sender];
```

When you set the `target` and the `action` of a button, you set which class is doing the action (`target`) and what method is called (`action`).

that's the equivalent of doing `[target action]`

Answer (score 0):

```
- (IBAction)logInBtnClicked:(id)sender {
    //Remove WhiteSpace from start of uitextfield
    self.emailIdTxtFldRef.text = [self.emailIdTxtFldRef.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    self.passwordTxtFldRef.text = [self.passwordTxtFldRef.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    if ([self.emailIdTxtFldRef.text isEqualToString:@""]||[self.passwordTxtFldRef.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        [self showMessage:@"All fields are mandatory" withTitle:@"Error"];
    }else{
        SWRevealViewController *revealVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"swRevealViewContoller"];
        revealVC.delegate=self;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow].rootViewController = revealVC;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your code and why it works or handles the problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.